# Shopify Schema publication?

Tags: shopify

Is there a publication of Shopify's schema somewhere?

I have read the [API Reference](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference) but need something deeper that describes in addition to field types, things like field max-lengths and any content formats or restrictions.

Some of this can be deduced from the API reference but not everything..

- for strings, it is not clear where they are using MySql Text field (64K), a string (255) or some other limitation (like metafield namespace which I believe is 30).
- Are email fields checked for valid addressing?
- Is the a prescribed format for phone numbers or is this just a short text field?
- Which fields are required?
- Which fields can be null or empty?

I am trying to design my API app to fit within their actual limits rather than find them through debug.

Thanks
Mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood correctly i think you are looking for [Shopify Input Settings](https://shopify.dev/themes/architecture/settings/input-settings) from the official documentation.

You can find anything about schema and the input types in that section. I am pretty sure it does not offer a list of the "required" fields but you can get sample code that you can easily use to build your schemas.

Also if you are looking for a more "automated" tool of creating schemas you can try [this](https://tkdallman.github.io/shopify-schema-builder/) out .

I hope this helps

Comment: Yes, although I am not developing against shopify atm, I see the documentation has vastly improved since 2016 :-) .   Both with Kshitij's answer below, great pointers for anyone stumbling on this post.  I'll mark both up.  
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can go through shopify api document with resource properties, like if you want to work with shopify product api then go through order properties, where they explain every single attribute properties:
https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/orders/order
 - fields limit
 - fields type
 - fields format
 - fields default values(null/empty/specific value)
 - fields required

for phone number and email shopify accept value as a string. There is no specific format validation.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, although I am not developing against shopify atm, I see the documentation has vastly improved since 2016 :-) .   Both with Octavians' answer, great pointers for anyone stumbling on this post.  I'll mark both up.  
Thanks.